# Ruby- gets issue

Tags: ruby, gets, puts

I'm currently in the process of learning ruby,  and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or the compiler is, but this code:

```
puts "Name?"
name = gets
puts "Welcome " + name
```

Outputs:

```
#blank line waiting for input, if gotten input
Prints input, Name? And Welcome Name
```

I want it to do something like python's input("Name? ")

Comment: I don't know how you could have got that result, but I think what you want requires two statements in Ruby: `print "Name? "`, followed by `name = gets`. Note that if the user enters `"Bob"` (followed by pressing the "Enter" key), `name` will be set equal to `"Bob\n"`. If you don't want the newline character it is common to write `name = gets.chomp`, which sets `name` equal to `"Bob"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own Python equivalent `input` method:

```
def input(prompt)
  print(prompt)   # Output prompt
  $stdout.flush   # Flush stdout buffers to ensure prompt appears
  gets.chomp      # Get user input, remove final newline with chomp
end
```

Now we can try it:

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
puts "Welcome #{name}"
```

For more information on the methods used here. See these:

- [`IO.flush`](https://apidock.com/ruby/IO/flush)
- [`String.chomp`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp)

Comment: Is there any way to make it easier? But still thanks a lot, exactly what I needed :)

Comment: The simplest piece of code that works, if you can accept a newline after the prompt is: `puts 'Name?'; name = gets.chomp; puts "Welcome #{name}"`.

Comment: That unfortunately produces ```Bob
Name?
Welcome Bob


Process finished.```

Comment: Are you running this in an IDE? Try it in your console. I don't think an IDE is good for user input processing like this. I.e. this smells like an IDE issue, and not a Ruby issue.

Comment: Yeah... I'm running it in decoder on android :D but in PC it should work as you have said earlier?

Comment: Yes. It works fine in the console on both Windows and Linux / OSX.